# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Signalr failing to connect on server as opposed to localhost

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have this implementation of Signalr in my Jquery

```
"use strict";
var SessionId = document.getElementById("Id").value;
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub?SessionId=" + SessionId)
    .build();
```

When I start the app on the localhost, I see this url in the Network tab

> https://localhost:44312/chathub/negotiate?SessionId=c71d63a0

It manages to load fine and my chat works.

However, when I deploy my app onto iis, I get this url

> http://st.live-url.com/chathub/negotiate?SessionId=6075a782

I get a 404 (Not Found) error instead.

May I know why the difference when its live? Must I install CORS for this to work?

Comment: its a asp.net core 2.2 project

Comment: If not related to API then nothing related to CORS!

Comment: Does work on Localhost properly?

Comment: Ah i see. I assumed that because I saw some signalr implementations saying to install it. And yes it works on localhost properly

Comment: `I get a 404 (Not Found) error instead.`- not getting the Hub url, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. It might have to do with the fact that in my iis server, there is the website name after the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187507/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-jianya).

Answer (score 0):

> It might have to do with the fact that in my iis server, there is the website name after the url.

That makes sense. Then you can't use `/chathub`. You either have to use a relative path (from the file where your JS code is):

```
"use strict";
var SessionId = document.getElementById("Id").value;
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("../chathub?SessionId=" + SessionId)
    .build();
```

Or inject the name of the virtual directory that your application is in (although you would want this to be configurable so you don't have to manually change it in prod vs. development):

```
"use strict";
var appRoot = "/myapp";
var SessionId = document.getElementById("Id").value;
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(appRoot + "/chathub?SessionId=" + SessionId)
    .build();
```

Also make sure that you install the Websockets protocol in IIS. That burned me just this week. If you need to do that, this should do it (in PowerShell):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets
```